# Why Cygnus not connected to another virtual machine with MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, fiware-cygnus

Good morning,

I have the following set of virtual machines:

- VM A

  - Generic Enablers Orion and Cygnus
  - IP: 10.10.0.10
- VM B

  - MongoDB
  - IP: 10.10.0.17

Cygnus configuration is:

/usr/cygnus/conf/cygnus_instance_mongodb.conf

```
#####
#
# Configuration file for apache-flume
#
#####
# Copyright 2014 Telefonica Investigación y Desarrollo, S.A.U
# 
# This file is part of fiware-connectors (FI-WARE project).
# 
# cosmos-injector is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify it under the terms of the GNU Affero General
# Public License as published by the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or (at your option) any
# later version.
# cosmos-injector is distributed in the hope that it will be useful, but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied
# warranty of MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE. See the GNU Affero General Public License for more
# details.
# 
# You should have received a copy of the GNU Affero General Public License along with fiware-connectors. If not, see
# http://www.gnu.org/licenses/.
# 
# For those usages not covered by the GNU Affero General Public License please contact with iot_support at tid dot es

# Who to run cygnus as. Note that you may need to use root if you want
# to run cygnus in a privileged port (<1024)
CYGNUS_USER=cygnus

# Where is the config folder
CONFIG_FOLDER=/usr/cygnus/conf

# Which is the config file
CONFIG_FILE=/usr/cygnus/conf/agent_mongodb.conf

# Name of the agent. The name of the agent is not trivial, since it is the base for the Flume parameters 
# naming conventions, e.g. it appears in .sources.http-source.channels=...
AGENT_NAME=cygnusagent

# Name of the logfile located at /var/log/cygnus. It is important to put the extension '.log' in order to the log rotation works properly
LOGFILE_NAME=cygnus.log

# Administration port. Must be unique per instance
ADMIN_PORT=8081

# Polling interval (seconds) for the configuration reloading
POLLING_INTERVAL=30
```

/usr/cygnus/conf/agent_mongodb.conf

```
#####
#
# Copyright 2014 Telefónica Investigación y Desarrollo, S.A.U
# 
# This file is part of fiware-connectors (FI-WARE project).
# 
# fiware-connectors is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify it under the terms of the GNU Affero General
# Public License as published by the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or (at your option) any
# later version.
# fiware-connectors is distributed in the hope that it will be useful, but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied
# warranty of MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE. See the GNU Affero General Public License for more
# details.
# 
# You should have received a copy of the GNU Affero General Public License along with fiware-connectors. If not, see
# http://www.gnu.org/licenses/.
# 
# For those usages not covered by the GNU Affero General Public License please contact with iot_support at tid dot es

#=============================================
# To be put in APACHE_FLUME_HOME/conf/agent.conf
#
# General configuration template explaining how to setup a sink of each of the available types (HDFS, CKAN, MySQL).

#=============================================
# The next tree fields set the sources, sinks and channels used by Cygnus. You could use different names than the
# ones suggested below, but in that case make sure you keep coherence in properties names along the configuration file.
# Regarding sinks, you can use multiple types at the same time; the only requirement is to provide a channel for each
# one of them (this example shows how to configure 3 sink types at the same time). Even, you can define more than one
# sink of the same type and sharing the channel in order to improve the performance (this is like having
# multi-threading).
cygnusagent.sources = http-source
cygnusagent.sinks = mongo-sink
cygnusagent.channels = mongo-channel

#=============================================
# source configuration
# channel name where to write the notification events
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.channels = mongo-channel
# source class, must not be changed
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.type = org.apache.flume.source.http.HTTPSource
# listening port the Flume source will use for receiving incoming notifications
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.port = 5050
# Flume handler that will parse the notifications, must not be changed
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.handler = com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.handlers.OrionRestHandler
# URL target
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.handler.notification_target = /notify
# Default service (service semantic depends on the persistence sink)
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.handler.default_service = def_serv
# Default service path (service path semantic depends on the persistence sink)
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.handler.default_service_path = def_servpath
# Number of channel re-injection retries before a Flume event is definitely discarded (-1 means infinite retries)
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.handler.events_ttl = 10
# Source interceptors, do not change
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.interceptors = ts gi
# Timestamp interceptor, do not change
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.interceptors.ts.type = timestamp
# Destination extractor interceptor, do not change
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.interceptors.gi.type = com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.interceptors.GroupingInterceptor$Builder
# Matching table for the destination extractor interceptor, put the right absolute path to the file if necessary
# See the doc/design/interceptors document for more details
cygnusagent.sources.http-source.interceptors.gi.grouping_rules_conf_file = /usr/cygnus/conf/grouping_rules.conf

# ============================================
# OrionMongoSink configuration
# channel name from where to read notification events
cygnusagent.sinks.mongo-sink.channel = mongo-channel
# sink class, must not be changed
cygnusagent.sinks.mongo-sink.type = com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.sinks.OrionMongoSink
# true if the grouping feature is enabled for this sink, false otherwise
cygnusagent.sinks.mongo-sink.enable_grouping = false
# the FQDN/IP address where the MySQL server runs (standalone case) or comma-separated list of FQDN/IP:port pairs where the MongoDB replica set members run
cygnusagent.sinks.mongo-sink.mongo_host = 10.10.0.17:27017
# a valid user in the MongoDB server
cygnusagent.sinks.mongo-sink.mongo_username =
# password for the user above
cygnusagent.sinks.mongo-sink.mongo_password = 
# prefix for the MongoDB databases
cygnusagent.sinks.mongo-sink.db_prefix = hvds_
# prefix for the MongoDB collections
cygnusagent.sinks.mongo-sink.collection_prefix = hvds_
# true is collection names are based on a hash, false for human redable collections
cygnusagent.sinks.mongo-sink.should_hash = false
# specify if the sink will use a single collection for each service path, for each entity or for each attribute
cygnusagent.sinks.mongo-sink.data_model = collection-per-entity  
# how the attributes are stored, either per row either per column (row, column)
cygnusagent.sinks.mongo-sink.attr_persistence = column

#=============================================
# mongo-channel configuration
# channel type (must not be changed)
cygnusagent.channels.mongo-channel.type = memory
# capacity of the channel
cygnusagent.channels.mongo-channel.capacity = 1000
# amount of bytes that can be sent per transaction
cygnusagent.channels.mongo-channel.transactionCapacity = 100
```

When performing the following steps:

I subscribe sensor and data persistently want to save :

```
(curl http://10.10.0.10:1026/NGSI10/subscribeContext -s -S --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --header 'Accept: application/json' -d @- | python -mjson.tool) <<EOF
    {
    "entities": [
        {
            "type": "Sensor",
            "isPattern": "false",
            "id": "sensor003"
        }
    ],
    "attributes": [
        "potencia_max",
        "potencia_min",
        "coste",
        "co2"
    ],
    "reference": "http://localhost:5050/notify",
    "duration": "P1M",
    "notifyConditions": [
        {
            "type": "ONTIMEINTERVAL",
            "condValues": [
                "PT5S"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
EOF
```

Then I make the creation or modification of such data:

```
(curl http://10.10.0.10:1026/NGSI10/updateContext -s -S --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --header 'Accept: application/json' -d @- | python -mjson.tool) <<EOF
{
    "contextElements": [
        {
            "type": "Sensor",
            "isPattern": "false",
            "id": "sensor003",
            "attributes": [
                {
                    "name":"potencia_max",
                    "type":"float",
                    "value":"1000"
                },
                {
                    "name":"potencia_min",
                    "type":"float",
                    "value":"200"
                },
                {
                    "name":"coste",
                    "type":"float",
                    "value":"0.24"
                },
                {
                    "name":"co2",
                    "type":"float",
                    "value":"12"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "updateAction": "APPEND"
}
EOF
```

The expected result is obtained, but when accessing the database of VM B, to see if they have created and saved the data, we see that it has not happened:

> admin      (empty)
>   local      0.078GB
>   localhost  (empty)

If we go to the database of VM A we can see who has created the database:

> admin          (empty)
>   **hvds_def_serv**  0.078GB
>   **hvds_qsg**       0.078GB
>   local          0.078GB
>   orion          0.078GB

Would I could indicate how it can solve?

Thank you in advance for your help

**EDIT 1**

I subscribe the sensor005

```
(curl http://10.10.0.10:1026/NGSI10/subscribeContext -s -S --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --header 'Accept: application/json' -d @- | python -mjson.tool) <<EOF
{
    "entities": [{
        "type": "Sensor",
        "isPattern": "false",
        "id": "sensor005"
    }],
    "attributes": [
        "muestreo"
    ],
    "reference": "http://localhost:5050/notify",
    "duration": "P1M",
    "notifyConditions": [{
        "type": "ONCHANGE",
        "condValues": [
            "muestreo"
        ]
    }],
    "throttling": "PT1S"
}
EOF
```

Then I edit data:

```
(curl http://10.10.0.10:1026/NGSI10/updateContext -s -S --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --header 'Accept: application/json' -d @- | python -mjson.tool) <<EOF
{
    "contextElements": [
        {
            "type": "Sensor",
            "isPattern": "false",
            "id": "sensor005",
            "attributes": [
                {
                    "name":"magnitud",
                    "type":"string",
                    "value":"energia"
                },
                {
                    "name":"unidad",
                    "type":"string",
                    "value":"Kw"
                },
                {
                    "name":"tipo",
                    "type":"string",
                    "value":"electrico"
                },
                {
                    "name":"valido",
                    "type":"boolean",
                    "value":"true"
                },
                {
                    "name":"muestreo",
                    "type":"hora/kw",
                    "value": {
                        "tiempo": [
                            "10:00:31",
                            "10:00:32",
                            "10:00:33",
                            "10:00:34",
                            "10:00:35",
                            "10:00:36",
                            "10:00:37",
                            "10:00:38",
                            "10:00:39",
                            "10:00:40",
                            "10:00:41",
                            "10:00:42",
                            "10:00:43",
                            "10:00:44",
                            "10:00:45",
                            "10:00:46",
                            "10:00:47",
                            "10:00:48",
                            "10:00:49",
                            "10:00:50",
                            "10:00:51",
                            "10:00:52",
                            "10:00:53",
                            "10:00:54",
                            "10:00:55",
                            "10:00:56",
                            "10:00:57",
                            "10:00:58",
                            "10:00:59",
                            "10:01:60"
                        ],
                        "kw": [
                            "200",
                            "201",
                            "200",
                            "200",
                            "195",
                            "192",
                            "190",
                            "189",
                            "195",
                            "200",
                            "205",
                            "210",
                            "207",
                            "205",
                            "209",
                            "212",
                            "215",
                            "220",
                            "225",
                            "230",
                            "250",
                            "255",
                            "245",
                            "242",
                            "243",
                            "240",
                            "220",
                            "210",
                            "200",
                            "200"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "updateAction": "APPEND"
}
EOF
```

These are the two logs generated:

[/var/log/contextBroker/contextBroker.log](http://pastebin.com/MW1CQVNL)

[/var/log/cygnus/cygnus.log](http://pastebin.com/VnR4y7sG)

**EDIT 2**

[/var/log/cygnus/cygnus.log with DEBUG](http://pastebin.com/keU3RR9y)

Comment: There are several things that would be useful for debugging this. Specially, both Orion and Cygnus logs. Regarding Cygnus, they must be under `/var/log/cygnus/cygnus.log`. Please, use a pastebin link if the log is large.

Comment: Thanks for Cygnus log. It shows the data is being received and, apparently, persisted. Nevertheless, if you don't see anything at MongoDB that means something is wrong with the connection. Could you run Cygnus in debug mode in order to know what is really happening with the connection between Cygnus and MongoDB?

Comment: The log in DEBUG mode does not show an error, but lines like this one: `time=07-01-2016T17:32:53.844CET | lvl=DEBUG | trans=1452184258-718-0000000000 | function=createCollection | comp=Cygnus | msg=com.telefonica.iot.cygnus.backends.mongo.MongoBackend[103] : Collection already exists, nothing to create`. That means the MongoDB driver is working properly, even the collection was already created in past executions.